Last two digits of a sequence
Consider the sequence
$$ a_{1} = 1,\,\ a_{n+1} = n^{\large a_n},\,\ \ {\rm so}\,\ \ a_{2} = 2^{1},\,\ a_{3} = 3^{2^{\large 1}},\,\
a_{4} = 4^{\large 3^{2^{1}}}
\qquad$$
How can we find  the last two digits of $a_{23}?$

One route which is certainly off-limits is to directly compute this. For instance, $a_5$ is already a number with more than 183000 digits. As such, even estimating the number of digits in $a_6$ likely not possible much less actually computing them.

$n!>!0\Rightarrow e := 22^{21^n}!\equiv0\pmod{!4};:$ $!!\bmod 5!:\  e\equiv  2^{21^n\bmod 4}\equiv 2^1$, so $,e\equiv \color{darkorange}{12}\pmod{!20}.,$ $20=\phi(\color{#0af}{25}),,$ so  mod $\color{#0af}{25}!:,$ $, 23^e \equiv (-2)^{\color{darkorange}{12}} \equiv 4096\equiv -4 \equiv  \color{#c00}{21}.,$ But $,2\mid e,$ so $!\bmod \color{#0a0}4!:\ 23^e\equiv (-1)^e\equiv 1\equiv \color{#c00}{21},,$ so $,23^e\equiv \color{#c00}{21}\pmod{!\color{#0a0}4\cdot \color{#0af}{25}},$ by CCRT.  Took one minute of mental arithmetic.

This is a duplicate of many prior questions. Since it has just been closed for other reasons I will suspend my search for good dupe targets. If you have questions about the above (general) method then you may pose them in comments below.

This is about sequences of powers modulo $100$. We may check that the order of $23 \:(\text{mod }100)$ is $20$. The values of $23^n \:(\text{mod }100)$ for $n = 1$ to $20$ are:
$$23, 29, 67, 41, 43, 89, 47, 81, 63, 49, 27, 21, 83, 9, 7, 61, 3, 69, 87, 1$$
As $a_{23}$ is $23$ raised to the power of $22$ (and so on), it is then pertinent to ask about the order of $22 \:(\text{mod }20)$. This is only $4$, and, for $m>1$, $22^m \:(\text{mod }20)$ takes the values $$12, 4, 8, 16$$ according to whether the power $m \equiv 1, 2, 3, 4 \:(\text{mod }4)$.
We almost might go in circles if not for the fact that:
$$
21^k \equiv 1 \:(\text{mod }4)
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus the power above $23$, namely $22^{21\dots}$, always ensures that the $1$st term of the $22$ sequence is selected, namely $\bf{12}$, and this ensures that the $12$th term of the $23$ sequence is selected, giving us $\bf{21}$ as the last two digits of $a_{23}$.

We don't need the order (only any period length), nor do we need to brute-force compute all terms in a periodic cyle - see my comment on the question. Brute force enumeration would be infeasible for larger numbers, but the method I explained still works easily.

Not sure my answer is the brutal one! I provided the answer I believed was at the level of the questioner.

The question contains no "level" context.  The method I give in the comment uses only basic results of elementary number theory.

First thing to realise, is that the last digit is repeated after four times, as you can see in the following table:



$a$
$a^2$
$a^3$
$a^4$
$a^5$




$1$
$1$
$1$
$1$
$1$


$2$
$4$
$8$
$6$
$2$


$3$
$9$
$7$
$1$
$3$


$4$
$6$
$4$
$6$
$4$


$5$
$5$
$5$
$5$
$5$


$6$
$6$
$6$
$6$
$6$


$7$
$9$
$3$
$1$
$7$


$8$
$4$
$2$
$6$
$8$


$9$
$1$
$9$
$1$
$9$



$a_{23} = 23^{22^{...}} = 23^{4^{...} \cdot ...}$, so you can easily derive that the last digit will certainly be a one.
For the last but one digit, you just create a similar table until you find a repeating pattern and you continue from there.
